# div goes down when page view 737 width w/ bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsive-images

i am stuck with this. I am working with the responsiveness of my custom site. I am using bootstrap. Why does my `<div class="col-xs-4">` goes down in a view of 737x width. Here is the screenshot :
[image: Screenshot]

i want the boxes of image to be in the right side of the text. my image are inside of the `<div class="col-xs-4">` 
Here is the jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26370/

here is my structure:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="row row-left">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-box2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-box2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-box2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-box2">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-left">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-box2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-box2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-box2">

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-box2">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

my css:

```
.col-box2 img {
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
}
.col-box2 {
   display:inline-block;
   float:none;
   text-align:left;
   margin-right: 3.6%;
   width: 15.6%;
   margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.row-left {
    margin-right: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Most likely because you are messing with the row and column margins. Those are an integral part of how the BS grid systems works, and you can not just go and change them willy-nilly, and expect things to still work properly.

Comment: how can i fix it sir?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: when i inspect the row sir, why does it goes full width ? when it is inside a <div col-md-8></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps you:
https://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/DTcHh/26371/

On line 3 and line 5 of your HTML you had

```
<div class="col-md-4">
```

and

```
<div class="col-md-8">
```

but when they collapse it also affects their children, in this case your `col-xs-4` elements

You'll see I've changed lines 3 and 5 of your HTML to

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
```

and

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
```

and all is good.

Comment: hello sir.. what a brillant answer.. thank you sir. you really helped me

Comment: Thanks, I'm pleased this helped @JcJohn . Often when troubleshooting layout type issues for myself I'll use this exact technique of applying a colour to the background of a div or element. It will often help narrow down the cause. Good luck with your work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use col-xs property with col-md just like

Col-xs property work below 767px but if we use col-xs property then content will look shrink and you have to manage content css according to view.

If we use col-md property then content will look with 100% width in mobile device.